# How can I use gsettings to configure settings with relocatable schemas?

Tags: compiz, settings

I am trying to configure a setting with `gsettings` in the Terminal, to avoid having to install special non-default applications to configure the settings. However, when doing so, `gsettings` complains the setting has a `relocatable schema` and does nothing.

```
#: gsettings set org.compiz.unityshell dash-blur-experimental 1
Schema 'org.compiz.unityshell' is relocatable (path must be specified)
```

How can I set the value with the `gsettings` command?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to specify the `path` to the key where the setting is actually stored. For example example, for this key, you need to use the `/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/` path when running the command, like so:

```
#: gsettings set org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/ dash-blur-experimental 1
```

Note that the path *must* end with a `/` character, when passed in for relocatable schemas.

Comment: And how can one find the required path for a particular scheme?

Comment: @Nicolay77, for example in dconf-editor GUI, copy path on top-left of the window. Last part I omitted as it is a key name.