# Where does the Guest Session store its configuration files

Tags: guest-session

In my computer I have my account (cyrex) and the guest session. If my user cyrex stores its files in `/home/cyrex` where does the guest session store its files?. For example, if I wanted to set the guest in a way so that when it loads it has a specific Wallpaper, Launcher icon size and any other customization I would want to do with it.

Comment: Is there a way to auto-hide the launcher? The users that will be using Ubuntu (call center) only need access to Firefox and it'd be great to free-up the extra inch of space that the launcher takes up.

Comment: @NYCTech There are several already answered questions related to "hiding the launcher". Feel free to search for them in Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just rewrote the tutorial [Customize Guest Session](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession). The main approach in the new tutorial - making use of a special purpose user account - is a more convenient way to customize the guest session feature.

Answer (score 5):

In `/tmp/guest-[xxxxxx]`, where the x's are a string of letters and numbers. That folder contains all the normal home folders for a user.

The guest account is managed by `lightdm` through `/usr/sbin/guest-account`, which is a shell script. After setting up the guest account, the script will run a preferences script if it exists: `/etc/guest-session/prefs.sh`

A convenience set of scripts to make this process easier, along with some explanation of how to use them, can be found at [CustomizeGuestSession](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession).

The basic settings you can change are:

```
Firefox preference settings
Disabling the login-sound
gettexted strings
Set a Folder for storing files permanently
Show an Info dialog at startup
Set an Icon on the desktop
Set the guest account language and keyboard
```

I haven't tested everything, but after using it a few times things seems to work well and seem easy to modify. I figured changing the language had the most potential for bugs, but I set the guest language to Chinese and it worked great.

Some things need to be added, such as changing the background.

There are two main files `prefs.sh`, which runs as root and then calls `auto.sh`, which runs as the guest user, as it finishes.

Features can be added to either file as appropriate. To change the wallpaper I added the following line to `auto.sh`.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///usr/share/backgrounds/Leftover_by_Sagar_jain.jpg"
```

Launcher icon size was a little trickier since it is a relocatable schema and DConf Editor says it has *No schema*, but the command is:

```
gesettings set org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/ icon-size 32
```

Thanks to @dobey for [an explanation of using relocatable schemas](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290159/how-can-i-use-gsettings-to-configure-settings-with-relocatable-schemas).

The original scripts were posted on the Ubuntu Forums by Gunnar Hjalmarsson.

Comment: @luis-alvarado I originally answered before the question was edited to include setting the background, etc. I've edited the answer to cover the additional points. (Reposting of comment. I had a typo in your user name previously)